# Fishing/ Kayaking/ hiking in Acadia Maine

Tags: camping, fishing, kayaks

I am heading to Acadia, Maine this week for a one week camping, fishing, kayaking and hiking. I've been there once but just for couple hours.
Any recommendations for fishing spots in the island?
I reserved a spot in the Sealwall camp , so I will be doing saltwater fishing/kayaking